# foreach two arrays when one is twice bigger than second

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Ok so I have two arrays, and the second one is allways twice larger than first one:

```
$items1 = array('1', '2', '3');
$items2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

I know that i can foreach two arrays with same items count like this:

```
foreach ($items1 as $key => $item1)
{
echo $item1 . $items2[$key] . ', ';
}
```

This will give result like this: 1a, 2b, 3c....
But how to foreach thos two arrays to get result like this:
1ab, 2cd, 3ef?
aka echo first item from $items1 array, an then two from $items2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:

```
foreach ($items1 as $i => $item1)
{
    echo $item1 . $items2[$i * 2] . $items2[$i * 2 + 1] . ', ';
}
```

Comment: I would probably throw the result into an array as you'll have that trailing comma. +1 otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (array_combine($items1, array_chunk($items2, 2)) as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.implode($value)."\n";
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution, however other answer suits my situation better. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Nifty, but hard to understand. Remember kids: try to go easy on your fellow programmers. They'll love you for it. Promise.